# difference between "as" and "with"

Tags: difference

Could anyone please explain to me if there's any difference between the two sentences in meaning and style?

- As 2024 begins, will you support us?
- With 2024 beginning, will you support us?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: There is no difference in meaning, The second sounds less natural to me.

Comment: They're both *highly stylised / literary* utterances.  In "normal" English, *"Will you support us **in 2024**?"* (or just *...[again] **this year**?*).

Comment: Thank you for answering my question! I've learned a lot from your answers.

Answer (score 1):

At some high level, there isn't much difference.  You observe (in one way or another) that it currently close to the beginning of 2024, and you request support.

The first "As" is about time or reason.  You are saying that you request support at the time of the beginning of 2024

The "With" is about condition.  You note the current state as being the start of 2024, and so request support.

Without context, both present a non-sequitur. There is no clear link from the fact that it is the beginning of 2024, to requesting support.  Would you have requested support at the end of 2023?  Or in the middle of 2025? Without context it seems strange to ask for support *because* it is the start of 2024.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear and detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

The sentences below are *awkward* (for example, for fundraising):

As 2024 begins, will you support us?
With 2024 beginning, will you support us?

The reformulations below are more typical of what the OP seems to be trying to say.

- As we go into this new year in 2024, we would *like to ask for* your support.
- As we go into the new year, your support is vital to our organization.

"with 2024 beginning" does not sound right there, at the beginning of a sentence where you ask people to support you. It is usable of course in other contexts.

Beginning requests for support with short adverbial phrases like that, followed by a comma, does not seem to be the best style for doing so. They do not *lure the reader in*...

Comment: Thank you so much for the very helpful explanation!